# sqlite3 dll with cmake

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake

I'm trying to build a SQLite3.dll with cmake. I'm very green with cmake and dlls. With cmake and ninja i get a dll as output without any error messages. But the dll doesn't works. In the Project, I included the dll, i get unresolved extern references with any sqlite3 method i try. For example, if i use "sqlite3_open("test.db", &db)" 
I get unresolved extern reference error.
If i examine my dll with dependency walker, it shows no dependencies. So i guess i made something wrong building my dll and nothing gets exported.
My Makelists.txt is

```
project(sqlite3)

add_definitions(-DCOMPILE_SQLITE)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(sqlite3_headers sqlite3.h)
set(sqlite3_sources sqlite3.c)

add_library(sqlite3 SHARED sqlite3.h sqlite3.c)

install(TARGETS     sqlite3 
                    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
                    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
                    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/static
       )
```

In the sqlite3.h i wrote the makro:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_SQLITE
#define Export __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define Export __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

and in front of the declarations i wrote "Export". Like:

```
SQLITE_API Export int sqlite3_open(
const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

I thought that should work. But obviously it doesn't. Where is my failure?

Comment: ***Where is my failure?*** Did you link your test application to the import library  generated with your dll? You can't link to a dll.

Comment: Why not just follow the [official instructions](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html#building_a_windows_dll)? You shouldn't be editing sqlite3.h or sqlite3.c to add stuff either way.